# How can I measure the time netty 4.1 needs to send some data?

Tags: java, netty, netty4

I have a workload where I have a server and a client, both under my control. They communicate via a TCP connection using Netty 4.1. The state diagram looks like this:

```
Server              Client

params = f();
               --> 
                    res = compute(params);
               <--
store(res);
```

I want to measure the time they spend communicating via the network. This means I want the total runtime minus the runtimes of f, compute and res. But, in reality it's more complicated, so I can't measure all the other parts of my program reliably.

Can I measure the time netty takes for the transfer? If yes, how so?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to measure a network latency. If so, you could send timestamp from the client, receive it on the server and send back to the client. Once received, you could calculate the latency like `now() - receivedTimestamp` on the client side.

I suppose that you use some POJO for the application data packets, so you can add kind of `LatencyMeasure` system packet which will holds `long timestamp` (which you could get with `System.currentTimeMillis()` or with some library like Guava's `Stopwatch`). And on client receive you can do smth like this: `long latency = System.currentTimeMillis() - latencyPacket.getTimestamp()`.